# Exponent Rule Over The Complex

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> Prove: $$e^{z_1+z_2}=e^{z_1\cdot z_2}$$

$$e^{z_1+z_2}=e^{x_1+iy_!+x_2+iy_2}=e^{x_1}(cosy_1+isiny_1)e^{x_2}(cosy_2+isiny_2)=e^{x_1}e^{x_2}[(cosy_1cosy_2-siny_1siny_2)+i(cosy_1siny_2+siny_ycosy_2)]=e^{x_1}e^{x_2}[cos(y_1+y_2)+i(siny_1siny_2)]=e^{x_1}e^{x_2}e^{i(y_1+y_2)}$$

But how do I get to $e^{z_1\cdot z_2}$?

Comment: Good luck to prove this, because it is wrong. It is not true over the reals, hence cannot be true over the complex numbers. $1=e^0=e^{1+(-1)}\overset?=e^{1\cdot(-1)}=e^{-1}$.

Comment: @M.Winter yes, my bad, but thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$e^{z_1+z_2}=e^{z_1\cdot z_2}$ is not correct !  Take $z_1=0 , z_2=1$

correct is $e^{z_1+z_2}=e^{z_1}\cdot e^{z_2}$

Can you now finish your proof ?

Comment: That why, I tried to prove the wrong this! thanks!. I am almost done, just $e^{x_1}e^{x_2}e^{i(y_1+y_2)}=e^{x_1}e^{iy_1}e^{x_2}e^{iy_2}=e^{x_1+iy_1}e^{x_2+iy_2}=e^{z_1}\cdot e^{z_2}$

Answer (score 0):

Let $z_1=a+b i$, $z_2=c+di$ which make $$z_1 z_2=(ac-bd)+(ad+bc)i$$ and then $$e^{z_1z_2}=e^{(a c-b d)} \left(\cos (a d+b c)+i \sin (a d+b c)\right)=e^{(a c-b d)}\,e^{(a d+b c)i}$$